# If one's brother got divorced, the former sister-in-law is still considered to be a relative?

Tags: word-meaning

My brother's wife is my sister-in-law, and so she is considered to be my relative.

But if my brother gets divorced, is my former sister-in-law still considered to be a relative?

Answer (score 3):

No, but it probably doesn't matter.

You were never related by blood, and following a divorce, you are not related by marriage.

It is hard to imagine a situation in which it matters whether you are a relative or not. It doesn't prevent you from remaining close with the former in-laws.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Not "related" any more but possibly still "family".

My former brother-in-law (my sister's former husband, divorced) is no longer technically related to me, but he is still part of my extended emotional family as he is the father of three of my nieces and nephews.

Similarly, my mother's cousin's widow (second wife quite late in life) is still "family" by choice though no longer technically related.

This is USA context, though -- other cultures may see these connections differently.

It's also the case that people like this are sometimes considered "family if you want them to be".  My sister had two ex-husbands and one of them I consider family and one I don't.  Neither is "related" to me, though -- there is a connection that can be traced, but it's not by being currently related.

Answer (score -1):

Does a constructed family tree include the person and their offspring? They are family. Children of divorced parents exist, their genealogy is not affected by legal practice. In my humble opinion this question is directed more toward the genealogical aspect of relations rather than financial and legal separation of individuals. Most people in the US are married in a chapel, with vows that are not established by the state, either, but rather their EQ. In some cultures and truthfully in certain time periods of history, it wasn't necessary (nor did they have the ability) to establish a written document to prove bonding between a couple. The bond had to be recognized by the community.

Comment: So what exactly is your answer to the original question which asked whether a particular situation means that someone is a relative?